# VMstat explanation needed

Tags: munin, vmstat

can somebody explain me this graph please?

[image: VMStat]

What does it show? What those green peaks mean?

Comment: looks like measurement fragments (and display/rendering quirks with close to zero values) due to sampling frequency/duration mismatch or numerical instabilities and the particular value range that you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about how the graph was set up or what it is meant to monitor I'm going to take a guess that it's an attempt to show actual cpu state/time.  If that indeed is the case it's a pretty big fail.

Comment: I just installed munin. It is out of the box installation. Nothing was changed.